# Custom Emoji in discord embed

Tags: discord, bots, embed, emoji, discord-jda

[image][image]**I have a discord bot in JAVA, where embeds and custom emojis from another server are often used. When the embed pops up for the first time, all custom emojis are visible, but as soon as I "update" the embed using the button under it, all the emojis disappear.**

I tried to check if my bot is not delayed because it does not have time to insert an emoji when updating, but no. Most likely something related to discord, or I don't understand something.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/5279